# `jq` filter to selectively replace parent field with child

Tags: jq

I have many JSON objects where I would like to transform some objects to reduce redundancy and limit some depth.

For example, given:

```json
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "foobarList": {
        "foobar": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "raboofList": {
        "raboof": [3, 5, 7]
      }
    }
  ],
  "bazList": {
    "baz": 11
  },
  "foobar": {
    "barbazList": {
      "barbaz": [13, 17, 19]
    },
    "foobazList": {
      "foobaz": {
        "barfooList": {
          "barfoo": [23, 29]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... I'd like to "hoist" the values of all the fields that end in "List", e.g., `"foobarList"`.

So, the above would be transformed to:

```json
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "foobar": 2
    },
    {
      "raboof": [3, 5, 7]
    }
  ],
  "baz": 11,
  "foobar": {
    "barbaz": [13, 17, 19],
    "foobaz": {
      "barfoo": [23, 29]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried various filters, but so far I can only identify the "List$" fields with:

```
jq '.. |iterables |to_entries[] |select((has("key")) and (.key|type == "string") and (.key|test("List$")) )'
```

How can this transformation be accomplished with `jq`?

Here's a [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/9Cem8wiMuMw) to help getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following produces the answer you want, but may not meet your expectations in every respect:

```
def hoist:
  with_entries(if (.key | endswith("List")) 
                  and (.value | type == "object")
                  and (.value | keys_unsorted | length==1)
               then (.value | keys_unsorted[0]) as $k 
               | .key = $k
               | .value |= .[$k]
               else . end);

walk(if type == "object" then hoist else . end)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input is "hoistable" structurally, you could also operate on its stream representation:

```bash
[fromstream(tostream | del(.[0][] | select(endswith("List")?)))] | add
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/b1dIgP1y676)

Comment: Works great.  Some day I hope to understand it.  :-)

Comment: @rickhg12hs Try running `jq -c 'tostream' file.json` to see the complete structure in stream representation. All I do from here is deleting those field names that end with "List", which automatically reduces the depth of the corresponding values, and put everything together again using `fromstream`. (The `?` just prevents `endswith` from tripping up on array indices (which are numbers) as it processes strings only, and the `[…] | add` re-assembles the structure which may break apart into separate objects when hoisting onto top level).

Comment: Yes!  I put `debug` here and there to see the deconstruction/reconstruction of the stream.  This looks like a powerful and very useful technique.